# React Native IOS App crashed, CFRelease() called with NULL

Tags: react-native

I can't reproduce the error in debug-model. But in release app, after back and navigate a tab many times by use `react-navigation`, the app crashed. And I got the error by `sentry`.

Is the app crashing because there are too many threads? Every time navigate the tab, there was 4 http requests.

Thanks for your option. Below is the error:

```
OS Version: iOS 12.1 (16B92)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Crashed Thread: 22

Application Specific Information:
*** CFRelease() called with NULL *** > countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: > objectAtIndexedSubscript:

Thread 22 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x311d5df20         CFRelease
1   INKubatorApp                    0x202f00d48         _ZN5folly6detail15str_to_integralIxEENS_8ExpectedIT_NS_14ConversionCodeEEEPNS_5RangeIPKcEE
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311e7f600         <redacted>
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311d5d530         <redacted>
4   CoreFoundation                  0x311d5e114         <redacted>
5   INKubatorApp                    0x202e64a24         <redacted>
6   INKubatorApp                    0x202eab7c8         RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
7   INKubatorApp                    0x202eab524         RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3113a66c8         <redacted>
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3113a7484         <redacted>
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x311381fb0         <redacted>
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x311382af4         <redacted>
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x31138af14         <redacted>
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3117c00dc         _pthread_wqthread
```

My navigate code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('BillList',{ listType: 'investment' }) }>
```

`BillList.js`:

```
render(){
        return (
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <HeaderCom title={ this.getListTitle() }  backgEvent={ () => this.props.navigation.goBack() }/>
                <InvestmentTab screenProps={ this.props.screenProps } />    
            </View>
        )
    }
```

`InvestmentTab.js`:

```
const InvestmentTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    allBills: {
        screen: BillContent,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.all'),
        }
    },
    toBePaidBills: {
        screen: BillContent,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.to_be_paid')
        }
    },
    paidBills: {
        screen: BillContent,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.paid')
        }
    },
    closedBills: {
        screen: BillContent,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.closed')
        }
    },
}, {
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'top', // 修改导航的位置
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: commonStyle.main, // 选中的颜色
        inactiveTintColor: commonStyle.bill_tab_inactive,
        showIcon: false, // 是否显示小图标
        style: { // 可以设置tab的各种样式
            backgroundColor: commonStyle.white, //底部tab的背景颜色
            height: 56,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: commonStyle.border_color,
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: commonStyle.border_color,
            elevation: 0,
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        },
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            paddingTop: 3,
            marginHorizontal: -1,
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: commonStyle.main,
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width * .16,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '4.5%',
        },
        pressOpacity: 0.8,
    }
});

export default InvestmentTab;
```

`BillContent.js` is just a FlatList and I fetch data from server at `componentWillMount()`.

```
componentWillMount() {
        appStorage.getUser().then(user => {
            this.setState({ userId: user.user_id });
            this._onRefresh();
            this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this._onRefresh);
        });
    }
```

In release app, after back and navigate a tab(Which name is BillList, I am sorry about weird name) many times, the app crashed.

Comment: Can you provide your navigator code? I suspect there is a problem there.

Comment: Here is the code.
 `<TouchableOpacity  onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('BillList',{ listType: 'investment' }) }>
`. Thanks for your response. I think this is not the key, because it works good at begining times

Comment: I mean to update your answer with your TabNavigation configuration. It sounds like you're not properly unmounting and it's filling up the thread and crashing. In debug mode this will appear as your app being slow, but in release, your app will just crash.

Comment: Dude, I have updated my question. Do you have any suggestion about the question?

Comment: The only thing I found is this [similar error reported here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55692). The comments might lead you to uncovering the issue. From a code standpoint, I can't see anything fundamentally wrong with your code. Perhaps using `BillContent` for all your tabs is leading to an issue, try duplicating it to separate files to test the theory.

Comment: Thanks, dude.I had checked the link you mentioned. I will try make some effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**, I thought it caused by too many http request and not correct usage about `react-navigation`. Below is my fix code:

My navigate code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyTab',{ listType: 'investment' }) }>
```

`MyTab.js`, yeah, I make navigation not embedded in component which named `BillList.js`:

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    allBills: {
        screen: MyList,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.all'),
        }
    },
    toBePaidBills: {
        screen: MyList,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.to_be_paid')
        }
    },
    paidBills: {
        screen: MyList,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.paid')
        }
    },
    closedBills: {
        screen: MyList,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('investment.closed')
        }
    },
}, {
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'top', // 修改导航的位置
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

`MyList.js`, I changed the weird name and only request data by `axios` in navigation 'didFocus' life event:

```
componentDidMount() {
        appStorage.getUser().then(user => {
            this.setState({ userId: user.user_id });
            this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this._onRefresh);
        });

    }
```

**Secondly**, I thought it caused by not canceled http request after component unmount, so I added `axios cancelToken`. Here is the code:

http request method:

```
getOrderArr(type, storage_user_id, page, callback, errCallback, navigation, listType) {
        source = axios.CancelToken.source();
        let that = this;
        var query = this.setRequestData(type, page, listType);
        var resOrderArr = [];
        let config = {cancelToken: source.token};
        InkubatorSApi.send({method: 'GET', url: query.url, obj: query.data, config: config}, (res) => {
            if (axios.isCancel(res)) return;
            // do something
        }, navigation);
    }
```

`MyList.js` `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
        source && source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
        this.navigationFocusEvent && this.navigationFocusEvent.remove();
    }
```

**Finally**, I run app in debug mode used iPhone, after same operation. `Xcode` console a error:

```
Assertion failed: (_lock_), function __SCNetworkReachabilityRestartResolver_block_invoke, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/configd/configd-963.200.27/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkReachability.c, line 1772.
(lldb)
```

At the same，`sentry` show a 0 http response status(which means request unreachable). Here is error image link(I have not enough reputation to upload image):
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL76B.png)

So I think it maybe caused by IOS, not my code. Who knows?